# dialect.getSequenceNextValString replacement

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot-3, dialect

I'm upgrading to spring 3.0 and one issue I'm encountering is that dialect.getSequenceNextValString is deprecated and I'm just not sure how to replace it. It doesn't seem like dialect has anything that replace it, is there anything else I can use? Or would I need to restructure how that part of the code work? Thank you!

A bit of code below for reference how its being used.

```
private final String sequenceName;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(dialect.getSequenceNextValString(sequenceName));
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

That method has been moved to SequenceSupport interface.
You can use like:

```
dialect.getSequenceSupport().getSequenceNextValString(sequenceName);
```